# What is RMagick equivalent to ImageMagic command

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

What is RMagick equivalent to ImageMagic command:

```
compare -metric AE -fuzz 25% img1.png img2.png result.png
```

The following ruby code works fine, and it gives me the desired float value, but the resulting image does not get effected by fuzz.

```
img1       = Magick::Image.read("img1.png").first
img2       = Magick::Image.read("img1.png").first
img1.fuzz  = "25%"
img, float = img1.compare_channel(img2, Magick::AbsoluteErrorMetric)
img.save('result.png')
```

Comment: I have been looking for this answer all day today and as far as I can tell, it doesn't exist (at least not easily). rmagick simply does not have a way to save the fuzzed compared image in the way that imagemagick does. If anyone figures this out I would definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does work OK the way you used it. I am using rmagick (2.13.3)

sg like this worked for me for comparison.
playing around with the fuzz % it does make a difference...

```
require 'RMagick'
require 'pp'

include Magick
a = ImageList.new("/path/to/ref/asset/missing-thumbnail.jpg")
b = ImageList.new("https://url-to-check.com/getAssetImage/objId:2225296/videoVersionId:2225297/type:cover/width:138/height:200/imageId:2247209.jpg")
c = ImageList.new("/path/to/second/asset/imageId:189577.jpg")
#a.display
#b.display
c.fuzz = '20%'
diff = c.compare_channel(b, Magick::AbsoluteErrorMetric) 
if  diff[1] == 0
  puts "yeeey. they r identical..."
else
  puts "ojh. they r not the same..."
  #pp diff 
  puts diff[1]
end
exit
```